# Show/hide a plot's legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm relatively new to python and am developing a pyqt GUI. I want to provide a checkbox option to show/hide a plot's legend. Is there a way to hide a legend?

I've tried using pyplot's '`_nolegend_`' and it appears to work on select legend entries but it creates a ValueError if applied to all entries.

I can brute force the legend to hide by clearing and redrawing the whole plot but... it's  a terrible thing to do, especially with large data sets.

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 10):

Here's something you can try on the command line:

```
plot([3,1,4,1],label='foo')
lgd=legend()

# when you want it to be invisible:
lgd.set_visible(False)
draw()

# when you want it to be visible:
lgd.set_visible(True)
draw()
```

In a GUI program it's best to avoid pyplot and use the object-oriented API, i.e., `ax.legend` and `canvas.draw`.