# Remove the legend on a matplotlib figure

Tags: matplotlib, legend

To add a legend to a matplotlib plot, one simply runs `legend()`.

How to **remove** a legend from a plot?

(The closest I came to this is to run `legend([])` in order to empty the legend from data. But that leaves an ugly white rectangle in the upper right corner.)

Answer (score 444, accepted):

As of [matplotlib `v1.4.0rc4`](https://github.com/cimarronm/matplotlib/releases/tag/v1.4.0rc4), a `remove` method has been added to the legend object.

Usage:

```
ax.get_legend().remove()
```

or

```
legend = ax.legend(...)
...
legend.remove()
```

See [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2798) for the commit where this was introduced.

Comment: Doesn't work for matplotlib 3.7.1

Comment: @irene sorry to hear it is not working for you.

This is still used in the unit test as of 3.7.1 and it worked when I just tried it: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.7.1/lib/matplotlib/tests/test_legend.py#L286-L294

What is the specific code that is not working for you?

Comment: `.remove()` part. Will try to run it again and see.

Answer (score 163):

If you want to plot a Pandas dataframe and want to remove the legend, add legend=None as parameter to the plot command.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5))
df2.plot(legend=None)
plt.show()
```

Comment: [The `legend` parameter is a `bool`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), so `legend=False` is probably better.

Answer (score 113):

You could use the legend's `set_visible` method:

```
ax.legend().set_visible(False)
draw()
```

This is based on a answer provided to me in response to a similar question I had some time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349202/show-hide-a-plots-legend)

(Thanks for that answer Jouni - I'm sorry I was unable to mark the question as answered... perhaps someone who has the authority can do so for me?)

Comment: For some reason, I get here "No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument"

Answer (score 29):

if you call `pyplot` as `plt`

`frameon=False` is to remove the border around the legend

and '' is passing the information that no variable should be in the legend

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.legend('',frameon=False)
```

Answer (score 20):

you have to add the following lines of code:

```
ax = gca()
ax.legend_ = None
draw()
```

gca() returns the current axes handle, and has that property legend_

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. (But what a horrible interface...) I suggest to replace `draw()` by `show()`. Or is there a particular advantage in using `draw`?

Comment: `show()` would be OK if the graph update were the last command of a program.  `draw()` is fine, as it is the general graph update command.  You might for instance want to prompt the user for some input in a terminal after updating the graph, which cannot be done with the blocking `show()`.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the answer. Now I agree that `draw` is more appropriate (but I've always used `show` to update my graphs...).

Answer (score 10):

According to the information from @naitsirhc, I wanted to find the official API documentation. Here are my finding and some sample code.

1. I created a `matplotlib.Axes` object by [`seaborn.scatterplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html).
2. The `ax.get_legend()` will return a `matplotlib.legned.Legend` instance.
3. Finally, you call `.remove()` function to remove the legend from your plot.

```py
ax = sns.scatterplot(......)
_lg = ax.get_legend()
_lg.remove()
```

If you check the [`matplotlib.legned.Legend`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend) API document, you won't see the `.remove()` function.

The reason is that the `matplotlib.legned.Legend` inherited the [`matplotlib.artist.Artist`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist). Therefore, when you call `ax.get_legend().remove()` that basically call [`matplotlib.artist.Artist.remove()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/artist_api.html#figure-and-axes).

In the end, you could even simplify the code into two lines.

```py
ax = sns.scatterplot(......)
ax.get_legend().remove()
```

Answer (score 6):

I made a legend by adding it to the figure, not to an axis (matplotlib 2.2.2). To remove it, I set the `legends` attribute of the figure to an empty list:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(range(10), range(10, 20), label='line 1')
ax2.plot(range(10), range(30, 20, -1), label='line 2')

fig.legend()

fig.legends = []

plt.show()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to the question in the title, which references a matplotlib *figure*.  The other answers tell you how to remove the legend from a matplotlib *axis*, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

If you are not using fig and ax plot objects you can do it like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# do plot specifics
plt.legend('')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Leaves the legend as an empty box

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more complex example of legend removal and manipulation with `matplotlib` and `seaborn` dealing with subplots:

From seaborn, get the `Axes` object created by `sns.<some_plot>()` and do `ax.get_legend().remove()` as indicated by @naitsirhc. The following example also shows how to put the legend aside, and how to deal in a context of subplots.

```py
# imports
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# get data
sns.set()
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(12,6)) 
fig.suptitle('Example of legend manipulations on subplots with seaborn')

g0 = sns.pointplot(ax=axes[0], data=tips, x="day", y="total_bill", hue="size")
g0.set(title="Pointplot with no legend")
g0.get_legend().remove() # <<< REMOVE LEGEND HERE 

g1 = sns.swarmplot(ax=axes[1], data=tips, x="day", y="total_bill", hue="size")
g1.set(title="Swarmplot with legend aside")
# change legend position: https://www.statology.org/seaborn-legend-position/
g1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)
```

[image: Example of legend manipulations on subplots with seaborn]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using seaborn you can use the parameter `legend`. Even if you are ploting more than once in the same figure. Example with some df

```
import seaborn as sns

# Will display legend
ax1 = sns.lineplot(x='cars', y='miles', hue='brand', data=df)

# No legend displayed
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x='cars', y='miles', hue='brand', data=df, legend=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply do:

`axs[n].legend(loc='upper left',ncol=2,labelspacing=0.01)`

`for i in [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]:`
`axs[i].legend([])`