# How do I make a single legend for many subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subplot, legend-properties

I am plotting the same type of information, but for different countries, with multiple subplots with Matplotlib. That is, I have nine plots on a 3x3 grid, all with the same for lines (of course, different values per line).

However, I have not figured out how to put a single legend (since all nine subplots have the same lines) on the figure just once.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 394, accepted):

There is also a nice function [`get_legend_handles_labels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels.html) you can call on the last axis (if you iterate over them) that would collect everything you need from `label=` arguments:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
fig.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper center')
```

If the `pyplot` interface is being used instead of the `Axes` interface, use:

```
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
```

To remove legends from subplots, see [Remove the legend on a matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5735208/7758804).

To merge `txinx` legends, see [Secondary axis with twinx(): how to add to legend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5484922/7758804).

Answer (score 139):

`figlegend` may be what you're looking for: *[matplotlib.pyplot.figlegend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figlegend.html)*

An example is at *[Figure legend demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/figlegend_demo.html)*.

Another example:

```
plt.figlegend(lines, labels, loc = 'lower center', ncol=5, labelspacing=0.)
```

Or:

```
fig.legend(lines, labels, loc = (0.5, 0), ncol=5)
```

Comment: I know the lines which I want to put in the legend, but how do I get the `lines` variable to put in the argument for `legend` ?

Comment: @patapouf_ai `lines` is a list of results that are returned from `axes.plot()` (i.e., each `axes.plot` or similar routine returns a "line"). See also the linked example.

Answer (score 88):

TL;DR

```
lines_labels = [ax.get_legend_handles_labels() for ax in fig.axes]
lines, labels = [sum(lol, []) for lol in zip(*lines_labels)]
fig.legend(lines, labels)
```

---

I have noticed that none of the other answers displays an image with a single legend referencing many curves in different subplots, so I have to show you one... to make you curious...

[image]

Now, if I've teased you enough, here it is the code

```
from numpy import linspace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# each Axes has a brand new prop_cycle, so to have differently
# colored curves in different Axes, we need our own prop_cycle
# Note: we CALL the axes.prop_cycle to get an itertoools.cycle
color_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']()

# I need some curves to plot
x = linspace(0, 1, 51)
functs = [x*(1-x), x**2*(1-x),
          0.25-x*(1-x), 0.25-x**2*(1-x)] 
labels = ['$x-x²$', '$x²-x³$',
          '$\\frac{1}{4} - (x-x²)$', '$\\frac{1}{4} - (x²-x³)$']

# the plot, 
fig, (a1,a2) = plt.subplots(2)
for ax, f, l, cc in zip((a1,a1,a2,a2), functs, labels, color_cycle): 
    ax.plot(x, f, label=l, **cc)
    ax.set_aspect(2) # superfluos, but nice

# So far, nothing special except the managed prop_cycle. Now the trick:
lines_labels = [ax.get_legend_handles_labels() for ax in fig.axes]
lines, labels = [sum(lol, []) for lol in zip(*lines_labels)]

# Finally, the legend (that maybe you'll customize differently)
fig.legend(lines, labels, loc='upper center', ncol=4)
plt.show()
```

- If you want to stick with the official Matplotlib API, this is
  perfect, otherwise see note no.1 below (there is a *private*
  method...)
- The two lines

  ```
  lines_labels = [ax.get_legend_handles_labels() for ax in fig.axes]
  lines, labels = [sum(lol, []) for lol in zip(*lines_labels)]
  ```

  deserve an explanation, see note 2 below.
- I tried the method proposed by the most up-voted and accepted answer,

  ```
   # fig.legend(lines, labels, loc='upper center', ncol=4)
   fig.legend(*a2.get_legend_handles_labels(),
              loc='upper center', ncol=4)
  ```

  and this is what I've got

[image]

---

Note 1
If you don't mind using a private method of the `matplotlib.legend` module ... it's really much much much easier

```
from matplotlib.legend import _get_legend_handles_labels
...

fig.legend(*_get_legend_handles_and_labels(fig.axes), ...)
```

---

Note 2

I have encapsulated the two tricky lines in a function, just four lines of code, but **heavily** commented

```
def fig_legend(fig, **kwdargs):

    # Generate a sequence of tuples, each contains
    #  - a list of handles (lohand) and
    #  - a list of labels (lolbl)
    tuples_lohand_lolbl = (ax.get_legend_handles_labels() for ax in fig.axes)
    # E.g., a figure with two axes, ax0 with two curves, ax1 with one curve
    # yields:   ([ax0h0, ax0h1], [ax0l0, ax0l1]) and ([ax1h0], [ax1l0])

    # The legend needs a list of handles and a list of labels,
    # so our first step is to transpose our data,
    # generating two tuples of lists of homogeneous stuff(tolohs), i.e.,
    # we yield ([ax0h0, ax0h1], [ax1h0]) and ([ax0l0, ax0l1], [ax1l0])
    tolohs = zip(*tuples_lohand_lolbl)

    # Finally, we need to concatenate the individual lists in the two
    # lists of lists: [ax0h0, ax0h1, ax1h0] and [ax0l0, ax0l1, ax1l0]
    # a possible solution is to sum the sublists - we use unpacking
    handles, labels = (sum(list_of_lists, []) for list_of_lists in tolohs)

    # Call fig.legend with the keyword arguments, return the legend object

    return fig.legend(handles, labels, **kwdargs)
```

I recognize that `sum(list_of_lists, [])` is a really inefficient method to flatten a list of lists, but ① I love its compactness, ② usually is a few curves in a few subplots and ③ Matplotlib and efficiency? ;-)

Comment: TLDR: Works but have caution if you have repeating labels

-

2023/10/10: Top answer didn't solve to me but yours did. My case was similar to yours, I needed all labels and handles from all axis - but some of them were equal in name, meaning and decoration, and some different. Thus, I had some duplication with your method that I need to get rid off. It's not your code's fault though.

Answer (score 21):

For the automatic positioning of a single legend in a `figure` with many axes, like those obtained with `subplots()`, the following solution works really well:

```
plt.legend(lines, labels, loc = 'lower center', bbox_to_anchor = (0, -0.1, 1, 1),
           bbox_transform = plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

With `bbox_to_anchor` and `bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure`, you are defining a new bounding box of the size of your `figure`to be a reference for `loc`. Using `(0, -0.1, 1, 1)` moves this bounding box slightly downwards to prevent the legend to be placed over other artists.

OBS: Use this solution *after* you use `fig.set_size_inches()` and *before* you use `fig.tight_layout()`

Comment: Or simpy `loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0), bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure` and it will not overlap for sure.

Comment: I'm still not sure why, but Evert's solution didn't work for me--the legend kept getting cut off.  This solution (along with davor's comment) worked very cleanly--legend was placed as expected and fully visible.  Thanks!

Comment: Note: "Evert" is now ["user707650"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834452/how-do-i-make-a-single-legend-for-many-subplots-with-matplotlib/9837940#9837940).

Answer (score 17):

You just have to ask for the legend once, outside of your loop.

For example, in this case I have 4 subplots, with the same lines, and a single legend.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

ficheiros = ['120318.nc', '120319.nc', '120320.nc', '120321.nc']

fig = figure()
fig.suptitle('concentration profile analysis')

for a in range(len(ficheiros)):
    # dados is here defined
    level = dados.variables['level'][:]

    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,a+1)
    xticks(range(8), ['0h','3h','6h','9h','12h','15h','18h','21h']) 
    ax.set_xlabel('time (hours)')
    ax.set_ylabel('CONC ($\mu g. m^{-3}$)')

    for index in range(len(level)):
        conc = dados.variables['CONC'][4:12,index] * 1e9
        ax.plot(conc,label=str(level[index])+'m')

    dados.close()

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0), loc='lower left', borderaxespad=0.)
         # it will place the legend on the outer right-hand side of the last axes

show()
```

Comment: `figlegend`, as sugested by Evert, seems to be a much better solution ;)

Comment: the problem of `fig.legend()` is that it requires identification for all the lines (plots)... as, for each subplot, I am using a loop to generate the lines, the only solution I figured out to overcome this is to create an empty list before the second loop, and then append the lines as they are being created... Then I use this list as an argument to the `fig.legend()` function.

Comment: A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001756/one-legend-for-all-subplots-in-pyplot)

Comment: What is `dados` there ?

Comment: @Shyamkkhadka, in my original script `dados` was a dataset from a netCDF4 file (for each of the files defined in the list `ficheiros`). In each loop, a different file is read and a subplot is added to the figure.

Comment: Note: "Evert" is now ["user707650"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834452/how-do-i-make-a-single-legend-for-many-subplots-with-matplotlib/9837940#9837940).

Answer (score 8):

To build on top of [gboffi's and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834452/how-do-i-make-a-single-legend-for-many-subplots-with-matplotlib/57484812#57484812) [Ben Usman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834452/how-do-i-make-a-single-legend-for-many-subplots-with-matplotlib/46921590#46921590):

In a situation where one has different lines in different subplots with the same color and label, one can do something along the lines of:

```py
labels_handles = {
  label: handle for ax in fig.axes for handle, label in zip(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels())
}

fig.legend(
  labels_handles.values(),
  labels_handles.keys(),
  loc = "upper center",
  bbox_to_anchor = (0.5, 0),
  bbox_transform = plt.gcf().transFigure,
)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using subplots with bar charts, with a different colour for each bar, it may be faster to create the artefacts yourself using `mpatches`.

Say you have four bars with different colours as `r`, `m`, `c`, and `k`, you can set the legend as follows:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
labels = ['Red Bar', 'Magenta Bar', 'Cyan Bar', 'Black Bar']


#####################################
# Insert code for the subplots here #
#####################################


# Now, create an artist for each color
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(facecolor='r', edgecolor='#000000') # This will create a red bar with black borders, you can leave out edgecolor if you do not want the borders
black_patch = mpatches.Patch(facecolor='k', edgecolor='#000000')
magenta_patch = mpatches.Patch(facecolor='m', edgecolor='#000000')
cyan_patch = mpatches.Patch(facecolor='c', edgecolor='#000000')
fig.legend(handles = [red_patch, magenta_patch, cyan_patch, black_patch], labels=labels,
       loc="center right",
       borderaxespad=0.1)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.85) # Adjust the subplot to the right for the legend
```

Comment: +1 The best! I used it in this way adding directly to the `plt.legend` to have one legend for all my subplots

Comment: It's faster to combine the automatic handles and handmade labels: `handles, _ = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()`, then `fig.legend(handles, labels)`

Answer (score 4):

Using Matplotlib 2.2.2, this can be achieved using the gridspec feature.

In the example below, the aim is to have four subplots arranged in a 2x2 fashion with the legend shown at the bottom. A 'faux' axis is created at the bottom to place the legend in a fixed spot. The 'faux' axis is then turned off so only the legend shows. Result:

[image: Some plot produced by Matplotlib]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# Gridspec demo
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 9)
fig.set_dpi(100)

rows   = 17 # The larger the number here, the smaller the spacing around the legend
start1 = 0
end1   = int((rows-1)/2)
start2 = end1
end2   = int(rows-1)

gspec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=4, nrows=rows)

axes = []
axes.append(fig.add_subplot(gspec[start1:end1, 0:2]))
axes.append(fig.add_subplot(gspec[start2:end2, 0:2]))
axes.append(fig.add_subplot(gspec[start1:end1, 2:4]))
axes.append(fig.add_subplot(gspec[start2:end2, 2:4]))
axes.append(fig.add_subplot(gspec[end2, 0:4]))

line, = axes[0].plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'b')         # Add some data
axes[-1].legend((line,), ('Test',), loc='center') # Create legend on bottommost axis
axes[-1].set_axis_off()                           # Don't show the bottom-most axis

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a complement to [user707650's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834452/how-do-i-make-a-single-legend-for-many-subplots-with-matplotlib/9837940#9837940) on the legend position.

My first try on user707650's solution failed due to overlaps of the legend and the subplot's title.

In fact, the overlaps are caused by `fig.tight_layout()`, which changes the subplots' layout without considering the figure legend. However, `fig.tight_layout()` is necessary.

In order to avoid the overlaps, we can tell `fig.tight_layout()` to leave spaces for the figure's legend by `fig.tight_layout(rect=(0,0,1,0.9))`.

[Description of tight_layout() parameters](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout).

Comment: This is a comment to one of the answers, and does not answer the question in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

All of the previous answers are way over my head, at this state of my coding journey, so I just added another Matplotlib aspect called patches:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

first_leg = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='1st plot')
second_leg = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='2nd plot')
thrid_leg = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='3rd plot')
plt.legend(handles=[first_leg ,second_leg ,thrid_leg ])
```

The patches aspect put all the data i needed on my final plot (it was a line plot that combined three different line plots all in the same cell in [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter)).

#### Result

(I changed the names form what I named my own legend.)

[image: I changed the names form what i named my own]