# matplotlib (python) - create single custom legend for multiple plots WITHOUT pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, legend

I would like to create a custom legend for multiple plots in matplotlib (python) in a pyqt GUI. (pyqt advises against using pyplot so the object-oriented method has to be used).

Multiple plots will be appear in a grid but the user can define how many plots to appear. I would like the legend to appear on the right hand side of all the plots therefore I cannot simply create the legend for last axes plotted. I would like the legend to be created for the entire figure not just the last axis (similarly to [plt.figlegend in pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9837940/3665119)).

In examples I have seen [elsewhere](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/figlegend_demo.html), this requires referencing the lines plotted. Again, I can't do this because the user has the possibility of choosing which lines to appear on the graphs, and I would rather the legend alway show all the possible lines whether they are currently displayed or not.

(Note the example code below uses pyplot but my final version cannot)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

# Create plots in 2x2 grid
for plot in range(4):
    # Create plots
    x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
    y = np.random.randn(len(x))
    y2 = np.random.randn(len(x))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,plot+1)
    plt.plot(x, y, label="y")
    plt.plot(x, y2, label="y2")

# Create custom legend
blue_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='blue',markersize=15, label='Blue line')
green_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='green', markersize=15, label='Green line')
ax.legend(handles=[blue_line,green_line],bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0),  loc='lower left', borderaxespad=0.)
```

[image: Plot with legend on RHS]

If I change ax.legend to:
    fig.legend(handles=[blue_line,green_line])
then python produces the error:

> TypeError: legend() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

(I guess because the line points aren't referenced)

Thanks for any help offered - I've been looking at this for a week now!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the error you are getting is because [`Figure.legend`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.legend) requires you to pass it both the `handles` and the `labels`.

From the docs:

> legend(handles, labels, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Place a legend in the figure. `labels` are a sequence of strings, `handles` is a sequence of `Line2D` or `Patch` instances.

The following works:

```
# Create custom legend
blue_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='blue',markersize=15, label='Blue line')
green_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='green', markersize=15, label='Green line')

handles = [blue_line,green_line]
labels = [h.get_label() for h in handles] 

fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels)
```

[image]

Comment: That's great tom - thank you so much for taking the time to answer!    I thought that the labels within the handles were being "read" by calling legend. Seems obvious now that you've showed me!