# Why all labels are not showing properly in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

When I am executing the below code, I can see the `Demo` is printing at the top horizontally. The `Demo2` prints inside the plot with `dotted line`. But I can't see the`Demo1`?
Why `Demo1` is not printing and why `Demo` is coming top horizontally?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
x = [1,2,3,4,5,-1-2]
y = [-1,5, 100, -2, 50, 100]
t = [100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150]
plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.title('Demo');
ax1.plot(t,x, 'b.:', label="Demo") # Showing top Horizontal 

ax2 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 2, sharex=ax1)
ax2.plot(t,y, 'b.:', label="Demo1") # Not showing up

ax3 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 3, sharex=ax1)
ax3.plot(t,t, 'b.:', label="Demo2") # This is perfect how I wanted

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you have a chance to try the solution in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`plt.figlegend()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figlegend.html) instead, which will give you output like this

[image]

Or call `plt.legend()` after each plot to add the legend to each subplot individually,

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
x = [1,2,3,4,5,-1-2]
y = [-1,5, 100, -2, 50, 100]
t = [100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150]
plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.title('Demo');
ax1.plot(t,x, 'b.:', label="Demo") # Showing top Horizontal 
plt.legend()

ax2 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 2, sharex=ax1)
ax2.plot(t,y, 'b.:', label="Demo1") # Not showing up
plt.legend()

ax3 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 3, sharex=ax1)
ax3.plot(t,t, 'b.:', label="Demo2") # This is perfect how I wanted
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If that's not exactly what you want there are other methods outlined in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834452/how-do-i-make-a-single-legend-for-many-subplots-with-matplotlib)