# Create a single legend for multiple seaborn plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I am making boxplot using "iris.csv" data. I am trying to break the data into multiple dataframe by measurements (i.e petal-length, petal-width, sepal-length, sepal-width) and then make box-plot on a forloop, thereby adding subplot.

Finally, I want to add a common legend for all the box plot at once. But, I am not able to do it. I have tried several tutorials and methods using several stackoverflow questions, but i am not able to fix it.

**Here is my code:**

```
import seaborn as sns 
from matplotlib import pyplot

iris_data = "iris.csv"
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
dataset = read_csv(iris_data, names=names)


# Reindex the dataset by species so it can be pivoted for each species 
reindexed_dataset = dataset.set_index(dataset.groupby('class').cumcount())
cols_to_pivot = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width']

# empty dataframe 
reshaped_dataset = pd.DataFrame()
for var_name in cols_to_pivot:
    pivoted_dataset = reindexed_dataset.pivot(columns='class', values=var_name).rename_axis(None,axis=1)
    pivoted_dataset['measurement'] = var_name
    reshaped_dataset = reshaped_dataset.append(pivoted_dataset, ignore_index=True)


## Now, lets spit the dataframe into groups by-measurements.
grouped_dfs_02 = []
for group in reshaped_dataset.groupby('measurement') :
    grouped_dfs_02.append(group[1])


## make the box plot of several measured variables, compared between species 

pyplot.figure(figsize=(20, 5), dpi=80)
pyplot.suptitle('Distribution of floral traits in the species of iris')

sp_name=['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
setosa = mpatches.Patch(color='red')
versi = mpatches.Patch(color='green')
virgi = mpatches.Patch(color='blue')

my_pal = {"Iris-versicolor": "g", "Iris-setosa": "r", "Iris-virginica":"b"}
plt_index = 0


# for i, df in enumerate(grouped_dfs_02):
for group_name, df in reshaped_dataset.groupby('measurement'):

    axi = pyplot.subplot(1, len(grouped_dfs_02), plt_index + 1)
    sp_name=['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
    df_melt = df.melt('measurement', var_name='species', value_name='values')

    sns.boxplot(data=df_melt, x='species', y='values', ax = axi, orient="v", palette=my_pal)
    pyplot.title(group_name)
    plt_index += 1


# Move the legend to an empty part of the plot
pyplot.legend(title='species', labels = sp_name, 
         handles=[setosa, versi, virgi], bbox_to_anchor=(19, 4),
           fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)


pyplot.show()
```

Here is the plot: 
[image]

**How, do I add a common legend to the main figure, outside the main frame, by the side of the "main suptitle"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To position the legend, it is important to set the `loc` parameter, being the anchor point. (The default `loc` is `'best'` which means you don't know beforehand where it would end up). The positions are measured from `0,0` being the lower left of the current ax, to `1,1`: the upper left of the current ax. This doesn't include the padding for titles etc., so the values can go a bit outside the `0, 1` range. The "current ax" is the last one that was activated.

Note that instead of `plt.legend` (which uses an axes), you could also use `plt.gcf().legend` which uses the "figure". Then, the coordinates are `0,0` in lower left corner of the complete plot (the "figure") and `1,1` in the upper right. A drawback would be that no extra space would be created for the legend, so you'd need to manually set a top padding (e.g. `plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(top=0.8)`). A drawback would be that you can't use `plt.tight_layout()` anymore, and that it would be harder to align the legend with the axes.

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches as mpatches
import pandas as pd

dataset = sns.load_dataset("iris")

# Reindex the dataset by species so it can be pivoted for each species
reindexed_dataset = dataset.set_index(dataset.groupby('species').cumcount())
cols_to_pivot = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']

# empty dataframe
reshaped_dataset = pd.DataFrame()
for var_name in cols_to_pivot:
    pivoted_dataset = reindexed_dataset.pivot(columns='species', values=var_name).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    pivoted_dataset['measurement'] = var_name
    reshaped_dataset = reshaped_dataset.append(pivoted_dataset, ignore_index=True)

## Now, lets spit the dataframe into groups by-measurements.
grouped_dfs_02 = []
for group in reshaped_dataset.groupby('measurement'):
    grouped_dfs_02.append(group[1])

## make the box plot of several measured variables, compared between species
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5), dpi=80)
plt.suptitle('Distribution of floral traits in the species of iris')

sp_name = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
setosa = mpatches.Patch(color='red')
versi = mpatches.Patch(color='green')
virgi = mpatches.Patch(color='blue')

my_pal = {"versicolor": "g", "setosa": "r", "virginica": "b"}
plt_index = 0

# for i, df in enumerate(grouped_dfs_02):
for group_name, df in reshaped_dataset.groupby('measurement'):
    axi = plt.subplot(1, len(grouped_dfs_02), plt_index + 1)
    sp_name = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
    df_melt = df.melt('measurement', var_name='species', value_name='values')

    sns.boxplot(data=df_melt, x='species', y='values', ax=axi, orient="v", palette=my_pal)
    plt.title(group_name)
    plt_index += 1

# Move the legend to an empty part of the plot
plt.legend(title='species', labels=sp_name,
           handles=[setosa, versi, virgi], bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.23),
           fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5, loc='upper right')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 8):

- The following implementation will refactor the code to generate the plot and add a figure legend as per [how do I make a single legend for many subplots with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834452/how-do-i-make-a-single-legend-for-many-subplots-with-matplotlib/46921590#46921590)
- [Matplotlib: Legend Guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/legend_guide.html)
- [`matplotlib.pyplot.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) and [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html)

  - `loc`
  - `bbox_to_anchor`
- See [Customizing legend in Seaborn histplot subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66353302/7758804) for `sns.histplot`, because `.get_legend_handles_labels()` does not work for it.
- The iris dataset is already part of `seaborn` and it loads as a dataframe.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.4`, `pandas 2.0.3`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

  - From `seaborn 0.13.0`, `legend=True` may be required in the `sns.boxplot` call.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# load iris data
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa

# create figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20, 5), sharey=True)

# add subplots
for ax, col in zip(axes, iris.columns[:-1]):
    sns.boxplot(x='species', y=col, data=iris, hue='species', dodge=False, ax=ax)
    ax.get_legend().remove()
    ax.set_title(col)

# add legend
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
fig.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper right', ncol=3, bbox_to_anchor=(0.8, 1), frameon=False)

# add subtitle
fig.suptitle('Distribution of floral traits in the species of iris')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

- However, **a legend is not required**, and redundantly conveys the same information, because the colors across each plot are the same, and the label for each is already on the x-axis.
- The more succinct option is to convert the dataframe to long format with `pandas.DataFrame.melt`, and then to plot with `sns.catplot` and `kind='box'`.

```py
dfm = iris.melt(id_vars='species', var_name='parameter', value_name='measurement', ignore_index=True)

  species     parameter  measurement
0  setosa  sepal_length          5.1
1  setosa  sepal_length          4.9
2  setosa  sepal_length          4.7
3  setosa  sepal_length          4.6
4  setosa  sepal_length          5.0

g = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=dfm, x='species', y='measurement', hue='species', col='parameter', dodge=False)
_ = g.fig.suptitle('Distribution of floral traits in the species of iris', y=1.1)
```

[image]

- Optionally, plot all the values in a single subplot, which makes comparing the `'parameter'` across `'species'` easier.

```py
g = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=dfm, x='parameter', y='measurement', hue='species', height=4, aspect=2)

_ = g.fig.suptitle('Distribution of floral traits in the species of iris', y=1.1)
```

[image]