# How to add hatches to histplot bars and legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, histplot

I created a bar plot with hatches using `seaborn`. I was also able to add a legend that included the hatch styles, as shown in the MWE below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

hatches = ['\\\\', '//']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,3))
sns.barplot(data=tips, x="day", y="total_bill", hue="time")

# loop through days
for hues, hatch in zip(ax.containers, hatches):
    # set a different hatch for each time
    for hue in hues:
        hue.set_hatch(hatch)

# add legend with hatches
plt.legend().loc='best'

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, when I try to create a histogram on `seaborn` with a legend, the same code does not work; I get the following error: `No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument.`

I've looked for an answer online, but I haven't been successful at finding one.

How can I add the hatches to the legend of a histogram for the MWE below?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

hatches = ['\\\\', '//']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,3))
sns.histplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", hue="time", multiple='stack')

# loop through days
for hues, hatch in zip(ax.containers, hatches):
    # set a different hatch for each time
    for hue in hues:
        hue.set_hatch(hatch)

# add legend with hatches
plt.legend().loc='best' # this does not work

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is `ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()` returns empty lists for seaborn.histplot. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346542/customizing-legend-in-seaborn-histplot-subplots). Use the [explicit interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-explicit-axes-interface) by adding `ax=ax` to `seaborn.histplot(...)`. Use `ax.get_legend().legend_handles` ([`.legendHandles` is deprecate](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/70e0ba8586e2d0bb38067154e077d920b218275b/doc/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.7.0/deprecations.rst#legendlegendhandles)) to get the handles for the legend, and add hatches with `set_hatch()`.

`ax.get_legend().legend_handles` returns the handles in the reverse order compared to the `container`, so the order can be reversed with `[::-1]`.

**Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

hatches = ['\\\\', '//']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3))
sns.histplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", hue="time", multiple='stack', ax=ax)  # added ax=ax

# iterate through each container, hatch, and legend handle
for container, hatch, handle in zip(ax.containers, hatches, ax.get_legend().legend_handles[::-1]):
    
    # update the hatching in the legend handle
    handle.set_hatch(hatch)
    
    # iterate through each rectangle in the container
    for rectangle in container:

        # set the rectangle hatch
        rectangle.set_hatch(hatch)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the previous accepted answer, with `matplotlib 3.4.2 seaborn 0.13.0`, I have to change `legend_handles` to `legendHandles`. As is said, the latter may be deprecated.