# How can I put two legend for subgraphs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subplot

I have 4 subgraphs, each has one legend for itself and I want to put a legend for the whole figure. I want to put it outside the plots.
I can do these separately as you can see on the figures. but I want to have them in one picture.

[image]

[image: n]

Comment: this question is duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834452

Comment: Your second picture looks fine. Can you explain more?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh I want to have both legends at one pic

Comment: @Mohammad Hosein No it is not. That question asks how to put one legend for many subplots. But my question is how to put two different legends ( one for the whole figure and the other for each subplot!)

Comment: Does [this](https://pastebin.com/dvw5xcse) program produces what [you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdyel.png)?

Comment: I want to have two legends in one figure. as you can see the first fig has power-law as a legend and the second has fit/real data as a legend. I want to have both legends in one figure @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: How about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb1W6.png) time with [this](https://pastebin.com/qnZHSwxZ) program?