# How to reposition matplotlib legend without plots to change

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a plot with 6 subplots with very similar data. I only want one legend and I would like to place it such that it overlaps two subplots, but it seems matplotlib prevents this. If I move the legend a bit up it changes the format of the subplots such that it doesn't overlap another plot. So my question would be: how to replace the legend without affecting the general make up of the subplots/how to allow overlapping?

I have tried both with `loc` and `bbox_to_anchor` but both reformat the subplots (i.e. changes axes)
Used syntax: `ax[1,1].legend(["line1",..,"lineN"],loc=(0.5,0.5)` and the same but loc replaced with bbob_to_anchor

EDIT:
I have just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921590/10220019) answer but it doesn't work for me I think because I'm not defining the labels inside the plot call. What I tried based on that answer was:

```
handles,labels = ax[1,1].get_legend_handles_labels()
    fig.legend(handles, ["line0",..,"lineN"], loc=(0.5,0.5))
```

But that gives me an empty legend. Just a little small square

EDIT2: A bit more clarification to my exact situation:

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots(3,2,  figsize=(10,8), sharex=True, sharey=True)
x = np.linspace(0,100,100)
y = np.random.rand(100,3)
ax[0,0].plot(x,y)
ax[0,1].plot(x,y)
ax[1,0].plot(x,y)
ax[1,1].plot(x,y)
ax[2,0].plot(x,y)
ax[2,1].plot(x,y)
//One single legend for the three lines represented in y. It should overlap part of subplot 0,1 and 1,1
```

Comment: May I know what type of plot are you having?

Comment: A normal plot. With x a normal vector and y matrix (non square but three vector basically)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oke I found the solution myself based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921590/10220019) answer but slightly different.
What worked is:

```
handles = ax[0,0].get_lines()
labels = ["line0",...,"lineN"] #obviously expand this and do not use ...
fig.legend(handles, labels, loc=(0.5,0.5)
```

So the trick is to use `get_lines` instead of `get_legend_handles_labels` if you haven't define labels in your plot calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something this:

```py
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,  figsize=(10,8), sharex=True, sharey=True)
l1,=ax1.plot(x,y, color='r', label='Blue stars')
l2,=ax2.plot(x,y, color='g')
l3,=ax3.plot(x,y, color='b')
ax1.set_title('Title')
plt.legend([l1, l2, l3],["label 1", "label 2", "label 3"], loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 3.2))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: True but in my case `y` actually represent three lines. So I'm not sure what `l1`, `l2`, etc. represents in that case

Comment: You can also just enable the legend for the plot where you want them and then just adjust legend. If you can post what you’re expecting then i could help you better.

Comment: I found already some thing that works for my case see my answer below. But thanks for your help anyway.