# Pandas plot() without a legend

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

Using the pandas library in python and using

```py
.plot()
```

on a dataframe, how do I display the plot without a legend?

Comment: Actually this question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735208/remove-the-legend-on-a-matplotlib-figure

Answer (score 204, accepted):

There is a parameter in the function corresponding to legend; by default it is True

```
df.plot(legend=False)
```

Following is the definition of the `.plot()` method

> Definition: df.plot(frame=None, x=None, y=None, subplots=False, sharex=True, sharey=False, use_index=True, figsize=None, grid=None, legend=True, rot=None, ax=None, style=None, title=None, xlim=None, ylim=None, logx=False, logy=False, xticks=None, yticks=None, kind='line', sort_columns=False, fontsize=None, secondary_y=False, **kwds)

Comment: To be precise, this is not really the correct answer since using `.plot()` automatically draws a legend, so it needs to be removed afterwards. In most cases, one would probably chose to use `.plot(legend=False)` but there are cases where you do not have that choice. Since I just encountered one, I added a new answer below.

Comment: This can also be used for variations like `df.plot.bar()` by using `df.plot.bar(legend=False)`

Answer (score 36):

In order to remove a legend that has once been drawn, use

```
plt.gca().get_legend().remove()
```

assuming that you have `import`ed `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` or

```
ax.get_legend().remove()
```

if `ax` is the axes where the legend resides.

Alternatively, see Nipun Batras answer if there is some choice to turn the legend off from the beginning in which case one can simply use

```
df.plot(legend=False)
```

Comment: This is crucial if you are using pandas **parellel_coordinates**, where the call to plot() is buried inside code that you can't easily access.  Using plt.gca().legend_.remove() **after** the call to parallel_coordinates successfully turned off the legend.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the `set_visible(False)` syntax because it aligns nicely with other syntaxes that hide stuff, such as hiding spines.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(11), 'B': 2, 'C': 5})

ax = df.plot()
ax.legend().set_visible(False)
ax.spines[['right', 'top']].set_visible(False)
```

[image: plot]