# Pandas - Stacked horizontal barchat for timeline?

Tags: python, pandas, charts, visualization

I'm looking at creating a timeline to show state changes for some items.

[image: timeline]

For each item, I have a list of events - e.g.:

- 08:00 - Item A is now in state RED
- 08:00 - Item B is now in state GREEN
- 08:55 - Item B is now in state PURPLE
- 09:00 - Item A is now in state BLUE
- 09:22 - Item A is now in state YELLOW
- 10:20 - Item B is now in state RED
  etc.

I'm using pandas, and was thinking of using the stacked horizontal barcharts (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#bar-plots):

[image: pandas stacked horizontal barchart]

However, the barchart in this case is backed by a dataframe like this:

`In [17]: df2
Out[17]:
          a         b         c         d
0  0.865681  0.276997  0.691200  0.077541
1  0.863821  0.465361  0.076636  0.013124
2  0.266339  0.359055  0.237709  0.698812
3  0.880864  0.198044  0.807911  0.889326
4  0.253440  0.080855  0.206936  0.603920
5  0.121422  0.880760  0.492782  0.841651
6  0.151359  0.264984  0.249734  0.136582
7  0.222347  0.007675  0.978766  0.267517
8  0.102839  0.847454  0.775913  0.519219
9  0.118314  0.347371  0.314426  0.308254`

I'm not sure of the most efficient way in pandas to map my timeline of events into something and plot it. I suppose I could convert the timestamps into duration (e.g. number of seconds), but I'd prefer the x-axis to display timestamps as per the first example above, so that may not work.

Is there a better of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide your input data please? I don't know what your 'list of events' looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, ax=ax)
ax.set_yticklabels(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
time = pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime('07:00', format='%H:%M'), end=pd.to_datetime('13:00', format='%H:%M'),freq='H')
time_x = [dt.strftime('%H:%M') for dt in time]
ax.set_xticklabels(time_x)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: remove legend using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735208/remove-the-legend-on-a-matplotlib-figure

Comment: Could you provide a full working code? I'm trying to figure out df's structure.