# How to remove the duplicate legend when overlaying boxplot and stripplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot, stripplot

One of the coolest things you can easily make in `seaborn` is `boxplot` + `stripplot` combination:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
data=tips, jitter=True,
palette="Set2", dodge=True,linewidth=1,edgecolor='gray')

sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
data=tips,palette="Set2",fliersize=0)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.);
```

[image]

Unfortunately, as you can see above, it produced double legend, one for boxplot, one for stripplot. Obviously, it looks ridiculous and redundant. But I cannot seem to find a way to get rid of `stripplot` legend and only leave `boxplot` legend. Probably, I can somehow delete items from `plt.legend`, but I cannot find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can [get what handles/labels should exist](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#controlling-the-legend-entries) in the legend before you actually draw the legend itself. You then draw the legend only with the specific ones you want.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
    
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, jitter=True, palette="Set2", dodge=True, linewidth=1, edgecolor='gray')

# Get the ax object to use later.
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="Set2", fliersize=0)

# Get the handles and labels. For this example it'll be 2 tuples
# of length 4 each.
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# When creating the legend, only use the first two elements
# to effectively remove the last two.
l = plt.legend(handles[0:2], labels[0:2], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 9):

I want to add that if you use subplots, the legend handling might be a bit more problematic. The code above, which gives a very nice figure by the way (@Sergey Antopolskiy and @Ffisegydd), will not relocate the legend in a subplot, which keeps appearing very stubbornly. See code above adapted to subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, axes = sns.plt.subplots(2,2)

sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
              data=tips, jitter=True, palette="Set2", 
              split=True,linewidth=1,edgecolor='gray', ax = axes[0,0])

ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
                 data=tips,palette="Set2",fliersize=0, ax = axes[0,0])

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

l = plt.legend(handles[0:2], labels[0:2], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

[image: duplicated legend]

The original legend remains. In order to erase it, you can add this line:

```
axes[0,0].legend(handles[:0], labels[:0])
```

[image: corrected legend]

Edit: in recent versions of seaborn (>0.9.0), this used to leave a small white box in the corner as pointed in the comments. To solve it use [the answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26845924/1379826):

```
axes[0,0].get_legend().remove()
```

Answer (score 3):

- [`sns.stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html): set `legend=None`
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns

# sample data
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# plot the stipplot without a legend
ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, jitter=True, dodge=True, edgecolor='k', linewidth=1, legend=None)

# add the boxplot to the same axes
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, ax=ax)

# move the legend
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)

# remove spines
ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
```

[image]