# How to overlay a scatterplot on top of boxplot with sns.catplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

It is possible to combine [axes-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html) plot functions by simply calling them successively:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, 
                   color=".25", alpha=0.7, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

How to achieve this for the figure-level function [`sns.catplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html)? Successive calls to `sns.catplot()` creates a new figure each time, and passing a figure handle is not possible.

```py
# This creates two separate figures:
sns.catplot(..., kind="box")
sns.catplot(..., kind="strip")
```

Comment: Note also [this](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1484) (open) seaborn issue addressing the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works for me with seaborn v0.11:

```py
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.catplot(x="sex", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", col="time",
                data=tips, kind="box",
                palette=["#FFA7A0", "#ABEAC9"],
                height=4, aspect=.7);
g.map_dataframe(sns.stripplot, x="sex", y="total_bill", 
                hue="smoker", palette=["#404040"], 
                alpha=0.6, dodge=True)
# g.map(sns.stripplot, "sex", "total_bill", "smoker", 
#       palette=["#404040"], alpha=0.6, dodge=True)
plt.show()
```

**Explanations:** In a first pass, the box-plots are created using `sns.catplot()`. The function returns a [`sns.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) that accommodates the different axes for each value of the categorical parameter `time`. In a second pass, this `FacetGrid` is reused to overlay the scatter plot ([`sns.stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html), or alternatively, [`sns.swarmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html)). The above uses method [`map_dataframe()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.map_dataframe.html#seaborn.FacetGrid.map_dataframe) because `data` is a pandas `DataFrame` with named columns. (Alternatively, using [`map()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.map.html#seaborn.FacetGrid.map) is also possible.) Setting `dodge=True` makes sure that the scatter plots are shifted along the categorical axis for each `hue` category. Finally, note that by calling `sns.catplot()` with `kind="box"` and then overlaying the scatter in a second step, the problem of [duplicated legend entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538882/) is implicitly circumvented.

[image: Resulting figure]

**Alternative (not recommended):** It is also possible to create a `FacetGrid` object first and then call `map_dataframe()` twice. While this works for this example, in other situations one has to make sure that the mapping of properties is synchronized correctly across facets (see the warning in the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)). `sns.catplot()` takes care of this, as well as the legend.

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time", height=4, aspect=.7)
g.map_dataframe(sns.boxplot, x="sex", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", 
                palette=["#FFA7A0", "#ABEAC9"])
g.map_dataframe(sns.stripplot, x="sex", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", 
                palette=["#404040"], alpha=0.6, dodge=True)
# Note: the default legend is not resulting in the correct entries.
#       Some fix-up step is required here...
# g.add_legend()
plt.show()
```