# how can I remove legend from the figure in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

Here is my diagrams,
[image]

I want to remove the labels of the second bar that is C1,C2,C3,C4,C5, because it is repeating.

Comment: See, for instance, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35539098/8881141