# How to clear matplotlib labels in legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Is there a way to clear matplotlib labels inside a graph's legend? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735208/remove-the-legend-on-a-matplotlib-figure) explains how to remove the legend itself, but the labels themselves still remain, and appear again if you plot a new figure. I tried the following code, but it does not work:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
labels = []
```

EDIT: Here is an example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.scatter([1,2,3], [4,5,6], label = "a")
legend = ax.legend()
plt.show()
legend.remove()
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
print(labels)
```

Output: `["a"]`

Comment: That wouldn't, as you're just re-binding the variable. There's no difference between that and expecting that `x = 42; x = 'hello';` would somehow change all `42`'s to `'hello'`.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `set_visible()` method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.scatter([1,2,3], [4,5,6], label = "a")
legend = ax.legend()
for text in legend.texts:
    if (text.get_text() == 'a'): text.set_text('b') # change label text
    text.set_visible(False)  # disable label
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to access the labels attribute of the legend directly? It would still be best if I could set it to some value manually.

Comment: Like here: `for text in legend.texts:                                                                  if (text.get_text() == 'a'): text.set_text('cc')`