# reduce decimals in legend sns

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, legend

I want to show only the `hr` and `min` in the legend

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x="time", y="qL",
                  hue="hr", style="hr", ci=0, palette="tab10",
                  markers=True, dashes=False, legend="full", data=file)
```

This is what I tried, but clearly it does not work. I also attach the resulting plot.

```
plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_texts()[:4])
```

Comment: `plt.setp` won't help you here. You can manipulate legend text like this: `for text in legend.texts: text.set_text(...)`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707853/how-to-clear-matplotlib-labels-in-legend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

You could:

- extract current legend labels with `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()`
- then manipulate them with `new_labels = [label[:-3] for label in labels]`
- finally, set the new labels through `ax.legend()`.

See the code below for example.

### Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([0, 1], [1, 2], label = '08:00:00')
ax.plot([0, 1], [2, 0], label = '10:30:00')
ax.legend(title = 'hr')

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
new_labels = [label[:-3] for label in labels]
ax.legend(handles, new_labels, title = 'hr')

plt.show()
```

### Output

[image]

### Note

Firstly I added a legend title with `ax.legend(title = 'hr')`, if you use seaborn, this will do it automatically. However, `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` does not extract legend title, only labels. In this way, when you set new labels, you need to specify the legend title again with `ax.legend(handles, new_labels, title = 'hr')`. Maybe there could be a more elegant way to do this.