# How to remove legend from an image plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, colorbar

I am trying to remove the legend of the spectrogram (I am trying to get a 244x244 pixel image)

I have tried [Remove the legend on a matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735208/remove-the-legend-on-a-matplotlib-figure) but it works in a very weird way - I get the result *and* an exception!

[image: colab exception and the result I want]

(I am using google colab)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import moviepy.editor as mpy

import youtube_dl
## downloading the video
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'wav',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pIpVK3Gecg'])

## selecting the audio clip from 17oth second to 180th second and saving it in talk.wav
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
ffmpeg_extract_subclip("Tyler, The Creator - 'IGOR,' Odd Future and Scoring a" 
                       "Number 1 Album _ Apple Music-5pIpVK3Gecg.wav", 170, 
                       180, targetname="talk.wav")


talk = mpy.AudioFileClip('talk.wav')
# switching axis off
plt.axis('off')

sample_rate = talk.fps
NFFT = sample_rate /25
audio_data = talk.to_soundarray()
#trying to get a 244 x 244 pixel image 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(2.44, 2.44), dpi=100.)

ax.axis('off')

spectrum, freqs, time, im = ax.specgram(audio_data.mean(axis=1), NFFT=NFFT, pad_to=4096, 
                                        Fs=sample_rate, noverlap=512, mode='magnitude', )


########## the problem lies here ##########
ax.get_legend.remove()

##trying to save stuff to drive but this doesnt run because of the exception
fig.colorbar(im)
fig.savefig('specto.png')

import os
print( os.getcwd() )
print( os.listdir('specto.png') )

from google.colab import files
files.download( "specto.png" )
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ax.get_legend` refers to the function object itself, `ax.get_legend()` (note parentheses) calls the function and returns a [`matplotlib.legend.Legend`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend) instance or `None`. The syntax should be

```py
ax.get_legend().remove()
```

However, if no legend has been added to the plot this will raise

> **AttributeError**: `NoneType` object has no attribute `remove`

so it is best to guard it with a `try` and `except` clause unless you know ahead of time that there will be a legend.

---

### Edit

Based on the comment, you are confusing [`matplot.pyplot.colorbar()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) with [`matplotlib.pyplot.legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html), hence why it "appears to work" when an exception is raised before the line

```py
fig.colorbar(img)
```

It simply never draws the colorbar because it doesn't reach that line. If you don't want a colorbar then remove the lines

```py
ax.get_legend().remove()

fig.colorbar(im)
```

and you will get a spectrogram without a colorbar.