# How do I get rid of the legend in Python using Pandas / pie charts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
# pie chart, have to fix the legend / get rid of it
pie = df_ppt_45.plot.pie(subplots=True,autopct='%1.1f%%', textprops={'fontsize': 8})

#plt.legend(pie[0],labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1,0), loc="lower right", 
                      #bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

[image: Pie Chart]

Here is the data frame just in case you need a reference.

[image: Data Frame]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the legend on a matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735208/remove-the-legend-on-a-matplotlib-figure)

Comment: you're using the pie function from pandas, so you can just add `legend=False`

Comment: `df_ppt_45.plot.pie(legend=False, subplots=True, autopct='%1.1f%%', textprops={'fontsize': 8})`